# How to read files created by the app by iOS WidgetKit?

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I am developing an app with widgetKit extension, and I want to show data created by the user on the widget. How can the widgetKit read files created by the app?

Comment: This answer might be helpful: [Share data between main App and Widget in SwiftUI for iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922032/share-data-between-main-app-and-widget-in-swiftui-for-ios-14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to read files created by the iOS widgetKit, you need to create files in the shared container

```
let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "yourapp.contents")?.appendingPathComponent("hello")
let data = Data("test read".utf8)
try! data.write(to: url!)
```

And you can read the data in the Widget class

```
@main
struct StuffManagerWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TestWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: TestIntent.self, provider: Provider()){ entry in
            WidgetEntryView(entry: entry, string: string)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
    
    var string: String = {
        let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "yourapp.contents")?.appendingPathComponent("hello")
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        return string
    }()
}
```

Comment: ATTENTION: When you run the app on real device, you have to configure the shared container in TARGET -> Capabilities -> App Group for both the app target and widget target

Comment: I get the error: Extra argument 'string' in call when writing this: (entry: entry, string: string)

Comment: This is great, but do you know if it's possible for the widget to read files created by the application? I am storing data in the ubiquitous container and can't seem to be able to read them from the widget.

Comment: @CristianMoisei By default, files are created with a 'not available until device is unlocked' flag, and widget code might run in such cases. You might need to modify file's attributes: `FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.protectionKey: FileProtectionType.none], ofItemAtPath: dataFolderUrl.path)`

Answer (score 5):

You should use **App Groups Capability** to share data between your targets.

Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiB8cf9xNzrAhVLWq0KHdXrA2EQygQwCnoECAsQCQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F11303363-getting-started-with-widgets%23toc-anchor-014&usg=AOvVaw08tG1ztxT1Z3u_w-4m_ury) by RayWanderlich