# Load image from app's documents folder (iOS 14 widget)

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, sandbox, ios14

I'd like to know if it's possible (and how!) to load a file saved in my main app's documents sandbox folder from a widget.

My main app (UIKit) saves images to `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]`. as a .png. I have a function to load these images from my app but would like to know how to load them in my widget timeline.

Here's my code for loading the images in UIKit:

```
    var documentsUrl: URL {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
}

private func loadImage(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {
    let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {
        print("Error loading image : \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

I've got app groups working as I'm using UserDefaults between targets fine.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you load them in the App? Please show your code.

Comment: You need to use the shared File Container specific for your App Group. See this answer: [Share data between main App and Widget in SwiftUI for iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63925053/8697793)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you can use **containerURL** with AppGroup ID

```
guard let urlPath = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: YOUR_APP_GROUP_ID)?.appendingPathComponent(YOUR_PATH_OR_FILE_NAME),
              FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: urlPath.path) else {
            throw DatabaseFileManagerError.cannotFound
        }
        
        
return urlPath
```

Lastly, make sure your AppGroup ID follows the guideline format **group.TEAM_ID.com.NAME_COMPANY.YOUR_APP_NAME**