# How to make data available across folders when creating iOS app widget?

Tags: swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I wanted to create widget for my app. I have used api to display data in my app. But I don't understand how to display the same data in widget. The classes/structs are not in scope. How to get around it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share data between main App and Widget in SwiftUI for iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922032/share-data-between-main-app-and-widget-in-swiftui-for-ios-14)

Comment: *"The classes/structs are not in scope"* - you can add the relevant files to the widget extension target.