# Pass UIKit Storyboard Data in to Widget with UserDefault

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

How to pass UIkit data in to widget extension and also get data in widget from User Default?

Second question is I have show dummy data in widget but getTimeline function only show first timeline other timelines not showing?

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {

    let data = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]

    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

    let currentDate = Date()
    for i in 0 ..< data.count {
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 60, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, loadEntry: 1, message: data[i])
        entries.append(entry)
    }
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apps and app extensions basically have different containers. 
Therefore, internal data such as userdefault and coredata are not shared with each other. 
However, there is a way to enable data sharing.

After you enable `app groups`, an app extension and its containing app can both use the `NSUserDefaults API` to share access to user preferences.

You can refer to the `app extension guide` for more information.

- [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1)

And I attach a link that seems to help you with your work.

- [Sharing data with a Widget](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/sharing-data-with-a-widget/)
- [Share data between main App and Widget in SwiftUI for iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922032/share-data-between-main-app-and-widget-in-swiftui-for-ios-14)

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed. If there is relevant code in the links please share that code. Links get broken over time

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn't know the detailed guidelines shortly after I started working on the site.