# Why don't interactive buttons in iOS 17 widget call AppIntent perform() when the app running?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, widgetkit

Inside a widget, there is a button,

```swift
Button(intent: AnAppIntent()) {
  // Button's label.
}
// It seems this modifier does not add any value.
.invalidatableContent()
```

connected to an AppIntent.

```swift
struct AnAppIntent: AppIntent {
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "An AppIntent"

  init() {
    // AppIntent required init.
  }

  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {

    // Never called when the app is running.

    return .result()
  }
}
```

The button calls AppIntent's `perform()` when tapped, and it consequently updates the widget UI (with or without the modifier `.invalidatableContent()`) **only when the app is closed completely**.

If the app is alive in the background, `perform()` is not called, and the widget UI never updates.

The user must explicitly dismiss the app to make the widget work as expected.

The problem may be in the timeline used.

```swift
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
  let date: Date
}

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
  func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
    SimpleEntry(date: Date())
  }

  func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
    completion(SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
  }

  func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

    // Generate a timeline of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
    let currentDate = Date()
    for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
      let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
      entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate))
    }

    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
  }
}
```

However, if the problem were the timeline, the widget would not work with the app dismissed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732771

Comment: You found any solution? I'm literally having the same problem

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue but on my side the "perform" method is executed (I can see it in the logs) but the UI of the widget is not refreshed, the timeline is not called to retrieve new timeline entries.

If the app is completely closed, the widget is working fine and is refreshed on each tap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file including the Intent needs to have a dual target membership: It needs to be part of both the widget extension target as well as the app target.

So make sure to tick those checkboxes.

Comment: I have dual target but I keep having this issue, to make sure I understood, the dual target should be set to the file where the intent is defined?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that my widget, which had dual target membership (it was in both my app & my widget target) still had this issue: **it was looking in the wrong location for data**.

I was using `UserDefaults` to store data about the current widget state, but *since [the widget code runs in different processes when the app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76673642/788168)* (with different state & "well-known" locations, assumedly), my calls to `UserDefaults` were reading a **different file** when the app was open vs closed.

> If you add the `AppIntent` to both your app and widget extension targets, the intent will run in your app process if your app is running (even if suspended in the background) and in the widget process when your app is not running. If you want it to always run in your app's process, you can implement `openAppWhenRun` which will cause your app to come to foreground, or you implement a different intent protocol that runs in the app's process in the background: `AudioPlaybackIntent`, `LiveActivityIntent`, or `ForegroundContinuableIntent`.

(via answer linked above)

---

### My fix

I mitigated this by storing my data in a custom [app group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups). [This answer offers different ways to use the AppGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63925053/788168), depending on your data.

In my case, I simply migrated from `UserDefaults` to using my SQLite DB I was already storing in the shared app group.